# Python gtk TextView border not working from css

Tags: python, css, gtk, gtk3

I have really strange situation. 
From the gtk css style I can apply for example background color, order radius, but i cant make the border to be visible. 
The file is ultra simple:

```
GtkTextView  {

    border-radius: 3px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    /*background-color: #0000ff;*/
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It might have to do with the current theme. Today I saw that my user-defined CSS border of an entry field is displayed in Linux Mint, but not when using another theme in Mageia (I use the standard themes on both installations).

Comment: I wasn't able to set a border for a text view, either. I'll try later today if I can manage in one of my virtual machines. Maybe you could give some info about your system?

Answer (score 1):

Also banged my head on this one for too many hours - much longer and might have broken google.  BTW: CSS borders don't work at all for this.

But it can be done by the Drawn signal.
Below code is C# (I'm not into python) but its short and 'll show the gist of it.

```
// add callback to Drawn signal handler
MyTextView.Drawn += widgetDrawn;  // where you build your form / set up your widget

....

// this works on any widget, labels and containers included
private void widgetDrawn(object sender, DrawnArgs e)
{
    e.Cr.SetSourceRGB(1, 0, 0);  // red - so ya won't miss it.
    e.Cr.Rectangle(0, 0, ((Widget)sender).Allocation.Width, ((Widget)sender).Allocation.Height);
    // thicker line --> e.Cr.LineWidth = 1;  // ... default is 1
    e.Cr.Stroke();
}
```

- It works on any widget including labels and containers
- the RGB is Cairo style (double prec.) 0.0000..1.0), i.e. light grey: (0.828, 0.828, 0.828)
- the line is drawn **inside** the allocated widget area (i.e. the wider you make `LineWidth` the less area left inside for your widget's contents.
- clipping is all taken care of (i.e. overlapping / beyond window borders)

**NOTE:** if instead you're overriding (inherited class or similar) with:  `protected override bool OnDrawn(Cairo.Context cr) { ... }`
-- call `base.OnDrawn(cr)` before you add the border,
-- and be sure to return the bool result.

Comment: What is the .Cr part here?

Answer (score 0):

My system is Mint with cinnamon . I don't remember theme name by heart, but I think that I've tried two or three. In the end I have added a frame not a perfect solution but it works.